# In a Spring Boot app with OpenTelemetry, how can I add an OpenTelemetryAppender for logs without changing the console logging?

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry, spring-logback

In a spring boot app, with Open Telemetry, when you have no logback.xml or logback-spring.xml there are console logs that include the traceId and spanId values.

I need to add an OpenTelemetryAppender, and thus I have to add a configuration file. This means I have to specify both OpenTelemetryAppender and ConsoleAppender, but ConsoleAppender needs an encoder and a pattern.

I don't want to change the pattern, I want to keep the existing pattern.

How could I do this?

Every attempt to specify no pattern fails with errors. Every example pattern I have found searching leaves out traceId and spanId.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the appender programatically, like [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-opentelemetry-starter/blob/main/src/main/java/com/grafana/opentelemetry/LogbackConfig.java#L19).

You can also just use a starter that adds the appender for you:

- [OpenTelemetry starter](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/automatic/spring-boot/)
- [Grafana OpenTelemetry starter](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-opentelemetry-starter) (I'm the author)
- The [JavaAgent](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/automatic/) is not a starter, but it will also send logs in the same way as the starters above

Comment: I'll give this method a try. Looks useful, thanks.

Comment: Nope, that won't work. At least not as is. I am not using grafana-opentelemetry-starter, so there is no LogAppenderConfigurer. Spring Boot 3.2.1 with actuator. Perhaps I can convert it to some sort of postConstruct...

Comment: I think it should work when you copy the LogAppenderConfigurer to your application.

Comment: Using Boot 3.2.1, and Actuator, there is no LogAppenderConfigurer anywhere. I think that is part of the older otlp starter library.

Comment: That's right - I'd suggest you manually copy [this file](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-opentelemetry-starter/blob/main/src/main/java/com/grafana/opentelemetry/LogbackConfig.java) to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <appender name="OpenTelemetry"
              class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.appender.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
        <captureExperimentalAttributes>true</captureExperimentalAttributes>
        <captureKeyValuePairAttributes>true</captureKeyValuePairAttributes>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="OpenTelemetry"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```